# css issue with url rewriting in php

Tags: php

i am  doing url rewriting on a website the issue that i am facing is the CSS misbehaviour ,the url rewriting works flawless but all the css gets messed up i need to add some ../ on css calls to make it right ,i want to know why is this happening and it is getting worse i may have to add two ../../ even,is there any generic way to handle this? currently working on apache help needed thanks in advance

[The Css Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Pe7.png)
[the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZDLQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using url rewriting, you have to provide absolute path to the css file.
According to your snapshot, the css file path should be like:

http://localhost/freefootball(sohail)/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css